# Call API from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to consume my own API from my web-application.

This is more or less what I want to do, but in the controller of my API:

In the Front-end two values are introduced by the user and these two should be sent to the API, then some calculations are done in my controller and finally I got the results in my view. I did already this, BUT let`s say in the normal controller (not that one in api/v1).

My index.html.erb is:

```
<div >
  <p class="mod1_title">Mein Lastprofil berechnen</p>
  <div class="mod1_boxed">
    <strong>Jahreshausverbrauch (kWh):</strong>
      <%= form_tag( '/calculation/index', post: true ) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module1", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 3500", id: "user_entry" %></br>

      <strong>PV-Große (kWp):</strong></br>
      <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module2", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 5", id: "user_entry_2" %></br>
      <%= submit_tag "Berechnen"%>

      <%end%>
  </div>  
</div>


Ergebnis: <%= @a %>
```

Could anyone point me how to achieve this?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are actually asking or attempting to do. If you want to update the current page without reloading then yes you do need use javascript/ajax. Please reply by editing your post and clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

To call the API from my Rails App. I used an AJAX call from javascript.